# Child viewController not receiving shouldAutorotate method call

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a UINavigationController with a UIViewController (VC1) pushed onto it. VC1 contains a collectionView. When a user taps a cell, a child viewController (VC2) is added to VC1.

VC2 should support all orientations. Whereas VC1 only supports portrait orientation. In portrait mode, I want to be able to present VC2, rotate into landscape, have VC2 adjust its layout accordingly, dismiss VC2, revealing VC1 still in portrait orientation/layout.

The shouldAutorotate method in VC2 gets called when VC2 is presented using the stock method. However this is insufficient because it doesn't allow a custom transition:

(1)

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CommentsViewController *vc = [[CommentsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CommentsViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The shouldAutorotate method is NOT called when using `presentViewController:animated:completion:` with a custom transition or using traditional viewController containment methods. In other words, neither of these work:

(2)

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CommentsViewController *vc = [[CommentsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CommentsViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.transitioningDelegate = [[TransitioningDelegate alloc] init];
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;
    vc.transitioningDelegate = self.transitioningDelegate;

    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

(3)

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CommentsViewController *vc = [[CommentsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CommentsViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self addChildViewController:vc];
    vc.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.view addSubview:vc.view]; // Assume I'm doing a cool custom animation here
    [vc didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

In summary, using approach #1 the rotation methods are called properly. But using #2 and #3 they are not. This prohibits me from building the required custom transition because doing so would mean the child viewController not supporting all orientations.

Any help would be much appreciated.

For background: I am versed in iOS6/7 rotation APIs, UIViewController containment, and custom viewController transitions.

**Edit:**

I did implement `shouldAutomaticallyForwardRotationMethods` to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this might not be what you need, but it seems like the presenting view controller maintains control of the shouldAutorotate call if your animated transition does not remove the presenting view controller's view. If you do remove the presenting view controller's view, then the control of the shouldAutorotate call moves up to the presented view controller.

I'm not sure how to send control automatically up without removing the view (so that you can show a transparent view), but you could just forward the shouldAutorotate call manually:

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate{
    if(self.presentedViewController){
        return [self.presentedViewController shouldAutorotate];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Not the most ideal though.

Comment: I've since solved this issue by taking a different approach, but I'm marking it as correct because I believe your assessment is on the mark and manually forwarding the call is perhaps all that can be done as a (albeit hacky) workaround. Thanks!

Comment: @AlfieHanssen Could you elaborate on the approach you took? I actually came across this exact same problem, but as I'm writing a library framework, my code can't force integrating code to forward the shouldAutorotate call. Wondering if you found any different ways around this.

Comment: If I'm remembering correctly I ended up circumventing viewController containment altogether, and using a UIWindow with a rootViewController (with it's own childViewControllers) instead. Using a UIWindow as the base for the view hierarchy I was trying to build provided a cleaner slate with less baggage. Make sense?

Comment: @AlfieHanssen Sounds about right. Actually came across that approach as well, but didn't work so well because I have two more layers of UIViewController on top of the root. But now that I think about it, I suppose could just do several layers of UIWindows. Way more hacky than I would really like, but oh well.

Comment: I have the same issue, but implementing this solution does not help. The presenting VC's `shouldAutorotate` never gets called upon rotation. The presented's does get called, returns NO, but rotates anyway.

Comment: @anas What presentation style are you using? It could be that some other view controller is being referenced (i.e. the presenting VC is not the root view controller, and the shouldAutorotate call chain is broken somewhere). Also, behavior differs based on whether you were compiling with iOS7 or iOS8 SDK (a huge pain).

Comment: @DavidLiu I'm using a UIModalPresentationCustom, and you're right, the call chain is probably broken. Nevertheless, I fixed my issue with this workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25892218/657104

Comment: @DavidLiu while presenting the VC2 shouldRotate never called up on VC1. I am using viewController containment methods.

Answer (score -1):

Did you happen to implement `- (BOOL)shouldAutomaticallyForwardRotationMethods` on the parent controller and have it return NO?

You case may be more complex, since you support different rotations for the different parent and child view controllers, but this is a easy gotcha to miss.

Comment: Unfortunately, or fortunately I did implement this.