# Prohibit rotation in iOS 8 for UIModalPresentationCustom modalPresentationStyle

Tags: ios, objective-c

I use this to present a clearColor UIViewController in iOS 8:

```
 self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;
 [_rootViewController presentViewController:self animated:NO completion:nil];
```

In this UIViewController I set

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
  return NO;
}
```

But I can rotate this viewController when self is presenting, When I use `self.modalPresentationStyle =UIModalPresentationCurrentContext` it will not clearColor but can not rotate. For UIModalPresentationCustom style how to prohibit rotation?

Comment: I have the exact same problem on iOS 7.. Ever found a way?

Answer (score 1):

I also tried to present a clear color UIViewController in iOS 8+ choosing UIModalPresentationCustom but failed to prohibit autorotation.

What worked for me was using `UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen` instead and the autorotation methods worked as intended:

> UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen
>
> > A view presentation style in which
> >     the presented view covers the screen. The views beneath the presented
> >     content are not removed from the view hierarchy when the presentation
> >     finishes. So if the presented view controller does not fill the screen
> >     with opaque content, the underlying content shows through.
>
> Available in iOS 8.0 and later.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue by adding this category on `UIViewController` in my AppDelegate. Not the greatest fix, but haven't found anything else useful so far.

```
@implementation UIViewController (customModalFix)

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    if ([self.presentedViewController isKindOfClass:[MyCustomPortraitOnlyClass class]]) {
        return [self.presentedViewController shouldAutorotate];
    }
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: This method does not solve my problem.When the presentingViewController can rotate,the presentedViewController should rotate too,no matter what you set in method: - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate.Thank you for your response.

Comment: Alright, this didn't fix it for me either on iOS 8 (although it did on 7). Did you ever find a way?

Answer (score 0):

I'm very late to this question but just run into the same issue, and found a solution.

The method shouldAutorotate seems to work inconsistently in iOS8 (in iOS7 worked great). What was worked for me perfectly in both 7 and 8 is the method supportedInterfaceOrientation.

All controllers in my app are portrait only, except one of them which I present it modally (with UIModalPresentationCustom), and want to support both portrait and landscape. This is how I did it:

### Solution

My app is driven by a NavigationController. Since UINavigationController takes control when deciding how its childControllers rotate, I subclassed the NavigationController and implemented the method for rotation:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    if (self.topViewController.presentedViewController && ![self.topViewController.presentedViewController isBeingDismissed]) {
        return self.topViewController.presentedViewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations;
    }
    return self.topViewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations;
}
```

So the method looks for a presentedController, if there is one it checks whether is being dismissed or not, if it is, it forwards the call to the topViewController (the presenting one, which only allows portrait). And if is not being dismissed (meaning the modal is rotating after it was already presented) I forward the call to the modal which allows all orientations.

Finally, If there isn't a presentedViewController at all, forwards the call to the topController which in my case all of them by default return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait.

### iOS 8 Issue

The issue in 8 is that when you have a modal VC presented, and then rotate to landscape successfully, if you then dismiss it to go back to the topController which should only allow portrait, the app remains in landscape unless you presented the modal in fullscreen mode. Why? Because iOS 8 only triggers the system orientation check that calls supportedInterfaceOrientations when modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen. This does not happen in iOS 7.

### iOS 8 Hack Solution

You can manually force rotation before dismissing. I wrapped it into a non animation block to make sure the user doesn't have to wait until the screen goes back to portrait every time they dismiss the modal from landscape. I made a Category on UIViewController to dismiss modals, which checks the OS version and performs the hack for 8. Here is the code:

```
 #import "UIViewController+Rotation.h"

@implementation UIViewController (Rotation)
- (void)dismissModalControllerAnimated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion {
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0")) {
        [UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
            NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
            [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
        }];
    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:flag completion:completion];
}
@end
```