# UIModalPresentationCustom messes up orientation settings

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

When presenting a modal with `UIModalPresentationCustom`, it ignores the orientation methods, and displays / rotates to whatever the presenting VC is configured to.

*Example*:

- Presenting VC supports Landscape and Portrait.
- Presented VC supports Portrait **only** (via `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` and `supportedInterfaceOrientations`.

When presenting it in landscape without `UIModalPresentationCustom`, it rotates the view back to portrait, then presents the VC accordingly. Unfortunately, because I need the presenting VC to stay visible below, I am forced to use `UIModalPresentationCustom`. And when that happens, the presenting VC is forced into landscape mode, creating a messed up UI and generating constraint issues. And even when presenting in portrait, it becomes allowed to rotate into landscape, ignoring that `shouldAutorotate` returns NO.

PS: I found a workaround on iOS 7 by adding this method to my App Delegate, but it doesn't fix it on iOS 8.

```
@implementation UIViewController (customModalFix)

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    if ([self.presentedViewController isKindOfClass:[IntroViewController class]]) {
        return [self.presentedViewController shouldAutorotate];
    }
    return YES;
}

@end
```

**EDIT**: Implementing `supportedInterfaceOrientations` on the presenting VC doesn't help at all, since it is only called when the view is loaded, not when a VC is about to be presented over it. Still haven't found a solution to this problem.

Comment: I run into the same problem today, here is the solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/29560217/1658831

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm late. The point is, when using UIModalPresentationCustom, the presenting VC will not disappear, and the presented VC is not considered to be presented full-screen (even if it does take up the full screen). Thus, it's the presenting VC that is consulted for the supported interface orientations. So the solution can be like:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if (self.presentedViewController) {
        return [self.presentedViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
    }
    return [super supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that doesn't work. - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations is only called when the presenting is first loaded, not when the presented is about to come on screen. So it never goes through the condition if (self.presentedViewController).

Answer (score 0):

If you only use `UIModalPresentationCustom` to keep the presenting VC visible below, say you need a clear colored VC, my answer here may work for you too:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29167837/4694080[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29167837/4694080)